# Sql to make generic query in order to get resultant table

Tags: sql

I have following table named tblItemLocations.

```
 locationName   pickRouteOrder  ispickable  itemnumber
    Loc1             124              1           10-001
    Loc2             126              0           10-001
    Loc3             128              1           10-002
    Loc4             130              0           10-004
    Loc44            136              0           10-004
    Loc5             131              1           10-007
    Loc6             133              1           10-008
```

Needed result :
Foreach itemnumber , there should be only one record with ispickable=1.
If Ispickable=0, then show No Loc.
Also total number of record is equal to total number of distinct itemnumber.
e.g in above table , there are 5 distinct itemnumber (10-001,10-002,10-004,10-007,10-008).
So there should be 5 records in result table.

```
Resultant table : 
locationName    pickRouteOrder      itemnumber
Loc1             124                  10-001
Loc3             128                  10-002
No Loc           130                  10-004
Loc5             131                  10-007
Loc6             133                  10-008
```

Can you please help to make query in order to get resultant table?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not really clear what you're asking. Is the result table what you want the query to do? Why does `itemnumber` matter?

Comment: What have you done so far? What is your database?

Comment: You say that `locationName` should be "No Loc" if an item has no record with `isPickable = 1`, but why is `pickRouteOrder` not also an indeterminate value? Specifically, why in your result table does item 10-004 have `pickRouteOrder` set to 130 and not 136? What happens if there are multiple records for a single item that have `ispickable = 1`? You said this _shouldn't_ happen, but that's not to say that it won't.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (tested using sql-sever and mysql):

```
select 
coalesce( max(case when ispickable = 1 then locationName
                   else null end ), 'no loc') as locationName, 
min( pickRouteOrder ) pickRouteOrder, 
itemnumber
from test 
group by itemnumber
```

The above does not generate the expected output when there are multiple records of an item and the one with the minimum pickRouteOrder is non-pickable (ispickable = 0).
Try below instead (modified from Gordon Linoff answer):

```
select locationName, pickRouteOrder, itemnumber
from test
where ispickable = 1
union all 
select 'no loc', min(pickRouteOrder), itemnumber -- use group by to eliminate multiple non-pickable records
from test t
where ispickable = 0 and 
      not exists (select 1 from test t2 where t2.itemnumber = t.itemnumber 
                  and t2.ispickable = 1)
group by itemnumber;
```

Comment: I need exact value of pickRouteOrder, not min (pickRouteOrder).
Can you please alter above query ?

Comment: In your sample data, item 10-004 has 2 pickRoute Order (130 & 136), you stated you only want 1 row with 130 on it. For those with just one pickRouteOrder, min(pickRouteOrder) is the same as pickRouteOrder.

Comment: @RizwanAli I see what you mean now. The min() picks up the minimum among pickRouteOrders of an item (pickable or not).  Why don't you take a look at Gordon Linoff answer.  You may need to modify the subquery on 'no loc' to eliminate the multiple non-pickable records of an item.

Answer (score 0):

If at most one row is pickable and unpickable (as with the sample data), you can also approach this as:

```
select locationName, pickRouteOrder, itemnumber
from t
where ispickable = 1
union all
select 'no loc', pickRouteOrder, itemnumber
from t
where ispickable = 0 and 
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.itemnumber = t.itemnumber and t2.ispackable = 1);
```

Under many circumstances, this will be faster than an aggregation solution, although I also like that version as well.